# how to add userid or other context aware data to every log in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am very new to JS and NestJS, but i am unable to find an example for this use case
I use NestJS and Pino Logger for my logging
specifically i use nestjs-pino

I have data on the JWT token and maybe other data on the request which i want to be part of any log line printed in my service.
For example userId and tenantID
And whenever i call log.debug() or log.info() (or any other level) that data will be part of the log (if available).

of course i want to avoid extracting that data and adding it to the log "manually" every time

If this was Java i would use MDC and just add that information to the log format. I am very new to Node/Nest and JS in general.

for code looking like this

```
log.debug("test")
```

I want the json log printed to include the tenantId (for example) if the flow started from an http request, even though i didnt actually include it in my call to log.

Answer (score -1):

use this decorator to get user data

decorator:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const GetUser = createParamDecorator((data, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return req.user;
});
```

for example you can use this decorator any where that you want
UserControler or PostControler or ...:

```
import { GetUser } from '../../auth/decorator/get-user.decorator';

  @Get('/')
  async findOne(
    @GetUser() user: User,
  ) {
    console.log(user.id)
  }
```

Comment: thats a good tip and ill use it, but it doesnt answer my question.
I want log like this
logger.debug("test this") to result in a log json that includes the userId
I dont want to manually get the userId in every place i call log.